# Nginx: Temporary Files Cleanup Automatically

Tags: nginx

I installed Nginx Admin (v4.5 Stable) in plugins of WHM. i feel it's making load on server when there a lot of files generated in /tmp/nginx_client/ directory. i want some cronjob which run Temporary Files Cleanup operation automatically. Or is there any predefined action to do this ? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open cron file:

```
crontab -u root -e
```

write down the following lines

```
#flush nginx tmp files.
# 360 = 6hrs
*/59 * * * * find /tmp/nginx_client/* -mmin +360 -delete
```

also [tmpwatch](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tmpwatch.htm) can help you.